# How can I get wanted part from string with regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a string like @'test'
 and I have to get only test word  without @' '

how can I match them with regular expression at javascript?

Comment: Why not just [`string.substr()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp) method?

Answer (score 0):

try the regex below:

```
@\'([^']*)\'
```

get `group(1)`

and if your language supports look-behind,( e.g. python, perl, java...):

```
(?<=@\')[^']*
```

should work too without grouping.

oh, just saw you edit your question, as far as I know, js doesn't support look-behind, then you could take the option 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
var firsName= "@'test'"
```

var objName = firsName .replace('@', "'");
lastName=objName.replace(/[']/g,'');

I fixed it like that. I dont know is it best way or not. thanks for helping